# Connecting to S3 bucket thru S3 VPC Endpoint inside EC2 instance timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am receiving "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" from inside EC2 instance running in private subnet

Here is a configuration:

1. Created one VPC with 2 private subnets (yes.. no public) that is
   connected to our datacenter using VPN connection. This VPC does not
   have any IG or NAT.
2. Created EC2 instance(Amazon Linux AMI) inside
   one of the private subnet.
3. Connected to EC2 using Putty-
   successfully.
4. Now created an endpoint - S3 that is connected to
   the VPC (in step1) and policy is as follows (as presented by aws
   management console):

   ```
   {
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Action": "*",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Resource": "*",
               "Principal": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Routing is automatically added to the VPC routing where destination is pl-xxxxxxxx(com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3) and target is
   the endpoint created in step4, status Active, Propogated - No
6. Added 2 outbound rules in Security Group for the VPC:  (HTTP:80, HTTP:443) to destination prefix s3 endpoint starting with
   pl-xxxxxxxx (same as step 5).
7. Created a bucket in S3 using amazon management console
8. Edited bucket policy as follows

   ```
       {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "Policy1459706251964",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt1459706246215",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": "s3:*",
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
9. Now entered following command in putty session

   ```
    aws s3 ls --debug --endpoint-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket
   ```
10. I got "EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL in #9

I know I am missing something..Any help will be greatly
    appreciated..

Comment: I'm not sure where you got `us-east1.s3.amazonaws.com`, but that's almost certainly invalid.  In the us-east-1 region, the correct endpoints for S3 are `s3.amazonaws.com` or `s3-external-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - You are right. In the AWS documentation, for east coast - it is s3.amazon.com. I tried it and it did not work. Then I googled and saw somebody had similar problem and he was referring to {us-east1.s3.amazonaws.com}. Now I re-corrected back and same error.

Comment: *Routing is automatically added to the VPC routing* ... automatically added?  That doesn't sound right, but I'm going from memory -- verify that *all* of the appropriate routing tables, particularly the one for the subnet of this instance do indeed have that pl-xxxxxxxx entry.  Then, I would relax the outbound security group to allow all traffic and see if you have a connection, then, or not. You don't want to have to troubleshoot more than one thing at a time.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Followed your instructions:

Comment: I also checked that <pl-xxxxx> is defined in subnet. Then I checked routing against the VPC. It is defined properly and it has  `3 routes defined- 1) <VPC CIDR> as Destination, "local" as Target, "Active" as Status and "No" as "Propogated" 2)<pl-xxxxxxx> as Destination, "<vpcendpoint>" as Target, "Active" as Status and "No" as "Propogated" 3) 0.0.0.0/0 as Destination, "<VGW>" as Target, "Active" as Status and "Yes" as Propogated` Then I relaxed the outbound rules on Security Groups associated with this VPC and allowed all traffic.

Comment: And then what happened?  If it's still not working, I'd be curious to see the result of a simple `telnet s3.amazonaws.com 443` since the error message "Could not connect" is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Can you open all outbound and see the CLI command succeeds? This will narrow down the debug route.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - The steps you originally asked me to verify -- did not work. However I am trying to do "telnet s3.amazonaws.com 443".. alas-- telnet not found on this ami. So I am struggling on that piece.. once i have that, I will post it here.

Comment: @helloV- Do you mean by open outbound rules for ALL Traffic. I did.. and CLI command did not succeed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  The problem is solved. The actual problem was inside our company firewall. The DHCP was not properly set to allow the traffic outside VPC and hence EC2 instance or accessing to any CLI commands.

Comment: @helloV - It was definitely related to permissions and as I mentioned to Michael - our IT Security Operations has not set these properly.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has similar problem- please also check with your corporate IT about DNS resolution properly set. The workaround is - While I waited for our internal IT to do this work, I used Amazon DNS.

Comment: Yes, that could do it.  There are several compelling reasons to stick with the VPC resolvers rather than using your corporate DNS servers.  You can associate "private" Route 53 hosted zones with your VPC as one way to resolve "internal" hostnames, if that's a concern.  Using external DNS that depends on the VPN connection will of course mean higher latencies and creates a dependency on the availability of the VPN connection for proper functioning of what you've deployed in AWS.